# CE 1.9.2 - Send Queued Transactional Custom Email

Tags: email, module, cron, ce-1.9.2.0, queue

I have a custom module working as I want it to that sends external stakeholders emails depending on the items in the order. I am observing the `sales_order_save_after` event and checking if the order status is set to *Processing*.

All works good using

```
$emailTemplate->send($emailSendAddress, $emailSendName, $emailTemplateVariables);
```

Now, the 2 payment method modules we are using automatically set the order status to *Processing" upon validation of payment, and the emails are sent immediately, and I do notice some slight latency while getting to the Checkout Success page (could be my imagination as well!).

Long story short ... How do I add my emails to the new email queue feature that was introduced with CE 1.9.1? Should I create a cron script for my module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the class `Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template` you can see the method `sendTransactional`. This method adds transactional e-mails to the queue.

I'm not 100% sure, but I'd expect the e-mail to be added to the queue if you use that method or a modified version of it.

Comment: Hi Milan. Thanks, I didn't realise that...reading up on it now and will post back here.